# Is there anything in Laravel equal to enable_profiler() in CodeIgniter?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, profiling

The CodeIgniter Profile Class will display benchmark results, queries you
have run, and $_POST data at the bottom of your pages. This
information can be useful during development in order to help with
debugging and optimization.

Is there anything in Laravel equal to `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in CodeIgniter?

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar might help you

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such built-in feature. You have to use some external package for that, like:

- https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
- https://github.com/daylerees/anbu